# MySQL - Use Header Name as Part of Query Filter

Tags: mysql

I'm relatively new to MySQL and have come across a problem to which I cannot seem to find a solution. I have searched but could not find an answer. I'm open to the possibility that I'm not asking the question correctly. Here goes:

I'm trying to use the name of a given column and the values within that column from one table to pull values from another table. The first table contains 3 columns with the response codified. The second table contains the definitions for each code for each item. The same number code is associated with different meanings depending on the item. For example:

```
table1 (this table cannot change):
--------------------------------------------------------------
|result_id | f_initial | l_name   | item_A | item_B | item_C |
--------------------------------------------------------------
|    1     |     j     |   doe    |   1    |   3    |   2    |
|    2     |     k     |  smith   |   3    |   1    |   2    |
|    3     |     l     | williams |   2    |   2    |   1    |
--------------------------------------------------------------


table2 (this table can be modified, split, or whatever needs to be done):
-------------------------------------------
|item_id | item_name | score | definition |
-------------------------------------------
|   1    |  item_A   |   1   |   agree    |
|   2    |  item_A   |   2   |  neutral   |
|   3    |  item_A   |   3   |  disagree  |
|   4    |  item_B   |   1   |   likely   |
|   5    |  item_B   |   2   | not likely |
|   6    |  item_B   |   3   |  no reply  |
|   7    |  item_C   |   1   |     yes    |
|   8    |  item_C   |   2   |     no     |
-------------------------------------------

My goal is for the query to output the following:
--------------------------------------------------------------------
|result_id | f_initial |  l_name  |  item_A  |  item_B    | item_C |
--------------------------------------------------------------------
|    1     |     j     |    doe   |   agree  |  no reply  |   no   |
|    2     |     k     |   smith  | disagree |   likely   |   no   |
|    3     |     l     | williams |  neutral | not likely |   yes  |
--------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Any assistance or guidance is greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must join the two tables on the `item_A/B/C` and `score` columns

```
select t1.result_id, t1.f_initial, t1.l_name,
       t2a.definition as item_a,
       t2b.definition as item_b,
       t2c.definition as item_c
from table1 t1
join table2 t2a on t2a.score = t1.item_a
join table2 t2b on t2b.score = t1.item_b
join table2 t2c on t2c.score = t1.item_c
where t2a.item_name = 'item_A'
      and t2b.item_name = 'item_B'
      and t2c.item_name = 'item_C'
```